# Проблема с заполнением массива

Tags: java

Создаю массив и заполняю его случайными числами:

```
public class Array {

    public static void randomized() {
        int[] a = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

когда вызываю метод

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array a = new Array();
        a.randomized();
    }
}
```

Получается это:

```
[I@25618e91
[I@25618e91
[I@25618e91
```

Что это и как с этим бороться? Раньше все работало нормально

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот так выглядит строковое представление ссылки на массив. Вы, видимо, хотите вместо него получить строковое представления содержимого массива. Это можно сделать так:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Array {

    public static void randomized() {
        int[] a = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете `System.out.println(a);` и в вывод получаете ссылку на массив, вместо конкретного элемента.

Исправьте на `System.out.println(a[i]);` и вы увидите все элементы массива