# вывод случайного byte[] в Java

Tags: java

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

```
private static byte[] getRandomData() {
    byte[] result;
    Random rnd = new SecureRandom();
    rnd.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
    result = new byte[Math.abs(rnd.nextInt() % 1024 * 10)];
    rnd.nextBytes(result);
    return result;
}
```

Такой код.
`result` всегда равен `[B@63947c6b`
А мне надо, чтобы случайно заполнялось

Comment: `[B@63947c6b` -- это не содержимое массива, а его адрес в памяти

Comment: Да, я так и понял. Но как мне сделать, чтобы содержимое массива выводилось?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с заполнением массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/768809/204271)

Answer (score 4):

У вас происходит вывод адреса в памяти объекта `result`. Чтобы вывелись значения из массива следует вывести каждое значение по отдельности.

Например, так(цикл `for`):

```
for(int i; i < result.length; i++) 
  System.out.println(result[i]);
```

или так(цикл `foreach`)

```
for(byte i : result) 
  System.out.println(i);
```

или так(Stream API), но этот код хуже по производительности чем предыдущие:

```
Arrays.stream(result).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Тогда будет выводиться не объект, а значения хранящиеся в нем.

Comment: @ИгорьХмелевский пожалуйста. Если ответ решил вашу проблему, то нажмите на стрелку вверх и галочку рядом с ним

Answer (score 2):

Для вывода содержимого массива в **java** удобно использовать метод `Arrays.toString`

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Генерировать же массив со случайными числами можно следующем образом:

```
private static byte[] getRandomArray(int size) {
    byte[] array = new byte[size];
    ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(array);
    return array;
}
```

Таким образом код целиком выглядет так:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRandomArray(10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через [DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary(byte[])) показать содержимое:

```
byte[] data = getRandomData();
String hex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data);
System.out.println(data); // [B@4dc63996
System.out.println(hex);  // B70FE2772D49E15B5D008B4E53560B2136C8AFC8F4FE7F47AAA41C5252ADE...
```

Comment: Ему разве это нужно? Мне кажется, что ему нужно просто вывести значение, не через hex

Comment: @AntonSorokin, hex один из способов представления байтовых массивов