# При заполнении массива случайными числами возникает ошибка ([I@61bbe9ba) для каждого элемента массива

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class massiv {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] myArray = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            myArray[i] = rand.nextInt(9);

            System.out.println(myArray );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не ошибка, а текстовое представление массива.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с заполнением массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/768809/204271)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо