# При конвертировании ArrayList в Array вывод очень непонятный. (Задача для новичка)

Tags: java, массивы

Пожалуйста, объясните как конвертировать ArrayList в Array (с целыми числами) и почему выдает такую строку? Буду премного благодарен!
Непонятный вывод: '[Ljava.lang.Integer;@6f539caf'
Код:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int a;
            while (console.hasNextInt() == true) {
                a = console.nextInt();
                arr.add(a);
            }
            Integer[] array1 = arr.toArray(new Integer[0]);
            System.out.println(array1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с заполнением массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768809/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычные массивы в Java так выводить нельзя, попробуйте так

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int a;
        while (console.hasNextInt() == true) {
            a = console.nextInt();
            arr.add(a);
        }
        Integer[] array1 = arr.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        // выводим каждый элемент массива
        for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
          System.out.println(array1[i]);

    }
```

Comment: можно проще `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));`